# Add-on triggers duplicate and stack a card that navigates back () to itself

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers, google-drive-api, google-workspace-add-ons

Building a Workspace Add-on for Google Drive, that lists files.

To my knowledge, this required two triggers.

- homepageTrigger - *when no files are selected*
- onItemsSelectedTrigger - *handling selected files*

I want them to show the same card, using the same function/code.

When the add-on loads, with selected files, both triggers, and the same Card gets duplicated and stacked. The top card navigates back () to itself. Going back creates a popup warning. Bad!

Can I avoid creating duplicate cards?

```
function homepageTrigger(e) { return dashboard(e) }
function onItemsSelectedTrigger(e) { return dashboard(e) }

function dashboard(e) {
  let dashboard = CardService.newCardBuilder().setName("CARD_DASHBOARD")
  selectedFromE(e).forEach(file => {
    dashboard.addWidget(widgetFromFile(file))
  })
  return dashboard.build() 
}
```

appsscript.json (essentials)

```
"addOns": {
  "common": {
    "homepageTrigger": {
      "runFunction": "homepageTrigger",
      "enabled": true
    }
  },
  "drive": {
    "onItemsSelectedTrigger": {
      "runFunction": "onItemsSelectedTrigger"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? It is hard to understand without seeing the (minimized) content of function `selectedFromE()`. Seeing your manifest might be also helpful for troubleshooting.

Comment: I want to display the files. When the addon opens, while files are selected, it runs dashboard twice. I want to do away with having the () back-arrow. selectedFromE() makes a list of selected files from e, if there are any.

Comment: I have a similar issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72621719/call-to-homepagetrigger-even-when-im-in-context