# Call to homepageTrigger even when I'm in context

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace-add-ons

I have this in my manifest:

```
"addOns": {
    "common": {
      "homepageTrigger": {
        "runFunction": "handleHomePageStart",
        "enabled": true
      },
      "name": "MyApp",
      "openLinkUrlPrefixes": [
        "https://www.myApp.com/",
      ],
      "useLocaleFromApp": true
    },
    "gmail": {
      "contextualTriggers": [
        {
          "unconditional": {},
          "onTriggerFunction": "handleStart"
        }
      ],
      "composeTrigger": {
        "selectActions": [
          {
            "text": "compose method",
            "runFunction": "handleStartCompose"
          }
        ],
        "draftAccess": "METADATA"
      }
    },
...
```

When I'm out of context, the homepage is displayed and I see in the executions a call for that method(`handleHomePageStart`). However, when I click on an email, both the homePage and context triggers are fired, as I can see both `handleHomePageStart` and `handleStart` executions in the list. Is this by design or my app has some flaw on it?

Thanks in advance!